# Spring Boot memory consumption increases beyond -Xmx option

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I noticed Spring Boot application does not obey the amount of memory set via Xmx option.
For example: java -Xss64m -Xmx64m -jar test.jar

I also printed on console the amount of memory really used by application at startup, and shows:
Max memory: 61M

```
long maxBytes = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
System.out.println("Max memory: " + maxBytes / 1024 / 1024 + "M");
```

When I open Windows processes before accessing any web page, it shows +-105M, so how can Java say 61M?

After accessing any web page it goes from +-125M to +-135M. Why is there such increase? It should give "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space" but do not increase this way.

It makes me get worried, if many applications could run out of memory at the server. By the way, I am using Java 1.8_45

Comment: You should read about the java memory model, especially about the changes in JRE 8. Xmx specifies the heap size, not PermGen. With Java 8, PermGen increases dynamically, if necessary. Also, the memory, which the program actually uses, and the memory which is blocked by the operating system, can be different.

Comment: Ok, but PermGen goes beyond Xmx so? I can't set anymore PermGen max in JVM 8

Comment: As i said, with Xmx you set the maximum size for the heap space, which is completely independent from permgen space. With Java 8, the permgen was actually removed and replaced by MetaSpace, which allocates the needed space directly from native memory. However, there is one option, where you can set the maximum size for the MetaSpace. See this article for more information: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After monitoring the Spring Boot application, I found out some possible reasons such as:

1. Number of http threads (Undertow starts around 50 threads per 
   default, but you can increase / decrease via property the amount of threads needed)
2. Access to native routines (.dll, .so) via JNI
3. Static variables
4. Use of cache (memcache, ehcache, etc)
5. If a VM is 32 bit or 64 bit, 64 bit uses more memory to run the same application, so if you don't need a heap bigger than 1.5GB, so keep your application runnnig over 32 bit to save memory.

Comment: 64 bit java uses compressed pointers (if you using less than 32GB xmx), so it shouldn't use more memory to run the same application?