# how to reduce spring boot memory usage?

Tags: java, memory, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot to develop a client application.
and when run the spring boot application(using a fully executable jar), the memory usage is about 190M in x64 server, and 110M in x86 server.

My JVM options are (-Xmx64M -Xms64M -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -server),
why is it that in the x64 server, memory usage is so big?
how to reduce memory usage below 150M?

thanks.

Comment: x64 (64-bit) pointers are twice as large as x86 (32-bit) pointers, so memory use in 64-bit mode will by necessity be larger.

Comment: yes, but I don't know what memory is used except heap + Perm.
I set max heap size 64M, max perm size 64M, but why around 60M(190M - 64Mx2) is used, and I can't reduce it.

Comment: @HailongLi you mentioned what is causing to increase memory. But how to reduce it ?

Comment: A little bit later, but this post may help https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-decrease-jvm-memory-consumption-in-docker-u

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Little late to the game here, but I suffered the same issue with a containerised Spring Boot application on Docker.  The bare minimum you'll get away with is around 72M total memory on the simplest of Spring Boot applications with a single controller and embedded Tomcat.  Throw in Spring Data REST, Spring Security and a few JPA entities and you'll be looking at 200M-300M minimum.  You can get a simple Spring Boot app down to around 72M total by using the following JVM options.

**With** `-XX:+UseSerialGC` This will perform garbage collection inline with the thread allocating the heap memory instead of a dedicated GC thread(s)

**With** `-Xss512k` This will limit each threads stack memory to 512KB instead of the default 1MB

**With** `-XX:MaxRAM=72m` This will restrict the JVM's calculations for the heap and non heap managed memory to be within the limits of this value.

In addition to the above JVM options you can also use the following property inside your `application.properties` file:

`server.tomcat.max-threads = 1` This will limit the number of HTTP request handler threads to 1 (default is 200)

---

Here is an example of `docker stats` running a **very** simple Spring Boot application with the above limits and with the docker `-m 72m` argument.  If I decrease the values any lower than this I cannot get the app to start.

`83ccc9b2156d: Mem Usage: 70.36MiB / 72MiB | Mem Percentage: 97.72%`

And here you can see a breakdown of all the native and java heap memory on exit.

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=1398681KB, committed=112996KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=36864KB, committed=36260KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=36864KB, committed=36260KB) 

-                     Class (reserved=1086709KB, committed=43381KB)
                            (classes #7548)
                            (  instance classes #7049, array classes #499)
                            (malloc=1269KB #19354) 
                            (mmap: reserved=1085440KB, committed=42112KB) 
                            (  Metadata:   )
                            (    reserved=36864KB, committed=36864KB)
                            (    used=36161KB)
                            (    free=703KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)
                            (  Class space:)
                            (    reserved=1048576KB, committed=5248KB)
                            (    used=4801KB)
                            (    free=447KB)
                            (    waste=0KB =0.00%)

-                    Thread (reserved=9319KB, committed=938KB)
                            (thread #14)
                            (stack: reserved=9253KB, committed=872KB)
                            (malloc=50KB #74) 
                            (arena=16KB #26)

-                      Code (reserved=248678KB, committed=15310KB)
                            (malloc=990KB #4592) 
                            (mmap: reserved=247688KB, committed=14320KB) 

-                        GC (reserved=400KB, committed=396KB)
                            (malloc=272KB #874) 
                            (mmap: reserved=128KB, committed=124KB) 

-                  Compiler (reserved=276KB, committed=276KB)
                            (malloc=17KB #409) 
                            (arena=260KB #6)

-                  Internal (reserved=660KB, committed=660KB)
                            (malloc=620KB #1880) 
                            (mmap: reserved=40KB, committed=40KB) 

-                    Symbol (reserved=11174KB, committed=11174KB)
                            (malloc=8417KB #88784) 
                            (arena=2757KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=1858KB, committed=1858KB)
                            (malloc=6KB #80) 
                            (tracking overhead=1852KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=2583KB, committed=2583KB)
                            (malloc=2583KB) 

-                   Logging (reserved=4KB, committed=4KB)
                            (malloc=4KB #179) 

-                 Arguments (reserved=17KB, committed=17KB)
                            (malloc=17KB #470) 

-                    Module (reserved=137KB, committed=137KB)
                            (malloc=137KB #1616)
```

Don't expect to get any decent performance out of this either, as I would imagine the GC would be running frequently with this setup as it doesn't have a lot of spare memory to play with

Comment: Lifesaver in 2020 with the `-XX:MaxRAM` setting for my heroku dyno constantly throwing R14 faults

Comment: 72 MB?! Ha!! Yeah right, my app *starts* at 950 MB. Spring boot 2.3.0, nothing more than a few REST controllers. It takes less than 10 seconds to start but even without receiving any requests, without putting any load on it, it shoots up to 1GB and stays there.

Comment: @JeneralJames This is exactly happening to me in production. And increasingly I feel this is not the technology for containerized world. This is truly made for monolithic application server and 100s of endpoints (controllers). That is why newer tech in Java space like quarkus is coming up to address exactly this issue. Even better platforms like Node/Go/.net core which are made grounds up for cloud / container native archs.

Answer (score 29):

After search, i found it's already have answer in stackoveflow.
[Spring Boot memory consumption increases beyond -Xmx option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125782/spring-boot-memory-consumption-increases-beyond-xmx-option)

```
1. Number of http threads (Undertow starts around 50 threads per default, but you can increase / decrease via property the amount of threads needed)
2. Access to native routines (.dll, .so) via JNI
3. Static variables
4. Use of cache (memcache, ehcache, etc)
If a VM is 32 bit or 64 bit, 64 bit uses more memory to run the same application, so if you don't need a heap bigger than 1.5GB, so keep your application runnnig over 32 bit to save memory.
```

because spring boot starts around 50 threads per default for http service(Tomcat or Undertow, Jetty), and its use 1 MB per thread(64bit jvm default setting).

SO the in 64bit jvm, the memory usage is
heap(64M) + Permgen(max 64M) + thread stacks(1M x 50+) + native handles.

references:

- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-decrease-jvm-memory-consumption-in-docker-u
- http://trustmeiamadeveloper.com/2016/03/18/where-is-my-memory-java/
- https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/04/openjdk-and-containers/

Comment: How to reduce this memory size ? is it because of jar file embedded tomcat server ? if we run it as war file memory will reduce ?

Comment: This accepted answer doesn't answer the question. The question was how to reduce memory consumption, not to explain why it was using a lot of memory.

Comment: why does this have 5 upvotes? it merely answers the question partly

Comment: Understanding why something happens helps with solving the problem. Both answers are good, the one goes in tiny details while the other gives a overview. They compliment each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can use -XX:+UseSerialGC as JVM Argument to specify Serial Garbage Collector which is best choice to reduce Memory Heap .