# I can't start the docker image built from spring-boot docker maven plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I recently tried the docker image building process using the `mvn spring-boot:build-image` command. I use the provided plugins that come with spring boot when I created the project with Spring Initializr. Here's part of the `pom.xml` that declares the plugins:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>docker.io/jeremy/${project.artifactId}:v1</name>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Below is the error I get trying to run the image from Window PowerShell:

[image]

Does anyone know what the error is and why it's happening? I'm pretty new to docker so I might have missed some important steps!

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: The description is too general, I think you need dig into.

Comment: @akortext I use the `mvn sping-boot:build-image` command, following this guide  [here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-docker/#using-the-spring-boot-plugin)

Comment: check out the logs. it tells you that more information can be found in /workspace/hs_err_pid1.log

Comment: @meaningqo I actually don't know where this file is placed

Comment: inside your container! if it's not there anymore because container crashed try running your container with sh or bash command and execute entrypoint command manually to reproduce the error and get the file written.

Comment: Error visible on screenshot shows that JVM has crashed, More info on what's on the screenshot: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/felog.html.  Can you get log file /workspace/hs_err_pid1.log from container? There's a very good document from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/index.html. Please see chapter "Troubleshoot System Crashes". Is 112 Mb enough for your app? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52993285/1206341)

Comment: @meaingqo i can't even start my container actually ,so i don't know if there's anyway i can access the log. I used the maven build image goal to generate this docker image, so no dockerfile was used