# Spring JPA taking too much time & memory for inserting data in postgres DB

Tags: performance, memory-management, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring batch app (with 2 GB memory) and trying to process data (used select queries to get data while processing) and inserting about 1 million processed records in postgres DB. I am using Spring Data JPA for this project. But Spring JPA is consuming too much memory while processing these records & finally i got out of memory exception. I suspected that there are too many entities created 
 which are not been cleared. Hence I tried to clear entityManager after certain DB calls, but didnt help. How can i reduce the memory consumption by JPA? Any suggestion to reduce memory consumption will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Reasons

- Number of http threads (Undertow starts around 50 threads per
  default, but you can increase/decrease via property the number of
  threads needed)
- Static variables
- Use of cache (memcache, ehcache, etc)
- Cascade Persist
- Batch Writing

---

`server.tomcat.max-threads=5`

This will limit the number of HTTP request handler threads to 1 **(default is 50)**
in your `application.properties`

For Details, you should refer [R1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491257/how-to-reduce-spring-boot-memory-usage) [R2](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html) [R3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125782/spring-boot-memory-consumption-increases-beyond-xmx-option)